# Python library to access a CalDAV server

Tags: python-2.7, caldav, owncloud

I run ownCloud on my webspace for a shared calendar. Now I'm looking for a suitable python library to get read only access to the calendar. I want to put some information of the calendar on an intranet website.

I have tried http://trac.calendarserver.org/wiki/CalDAVClientLibrary but it always returns a `NotImplementedError` with the query command, so my guess is that the query command doesn't work well with the given library.

What library could I use instead?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 8):

I recommend the library, [caldav](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/caldav/).

Read-only is working really well with this library and looks straight-forward to me. It will do the whole job of getting calendars and reading events, returning them in the [iCalendar format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar). More information about the `caldav` library can also be obtained in the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/caldav/index.html).

```
import caldav

client = caldav.DAVClient(<caldav-url>, username=<username>,
                          password=<password>)
principal = client.principal()
for calendar in principal.calendars():
    for event in calendar.events():
        ical_text = event.data
```

From this on you can use the [icalendar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/icalendar/3.9.0) library to read specific fields such as the type (e. g. event, todo, alarm), name, times, etc. - a good starting point may be [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408097/parsing-files-ics-icalendar-using-python).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I think the edit is what you asked for?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this code few months ago to fetch data from CalDAV to present them on my website.
I have changed the data into JSON format, but you can do whatever you want with the data.

I have added some print for you to see the output which you can remove them in production.

```
    from datetime import datetime
import json
from pytz import UTC # timezone
import caldav
from icalendar import Calendar, Event

# CalDAV info
url = "YOUR CALDAV URL"
userN = "YOUR CALDAV USERNAME"
passW = "YOUR CALDAV PASSWORD"

client = caldav.DAVClient(url=url, username=userN, password=passW)
principal = client.principal()
calendars = principal.calendars()

if len(calendars) > 0:
    calendar = calendars[0]
    print ("Using calendar", calendar)
    results = calendar.events()
    eventSummary = []
    eventDescription = []
    eventDateStart = []
    eventdateEnd = []
    eventTimeStart = []
    eventTimeEnd = []

    for eventraw in results:

        event = Calendar.from_ical(eventraw._data)
        for component in event.walk():
            if component.name == "VEVENT":
                print (component.get('summary'))
                eventSummary.append(component.get('summary'))
                print (component.get('description'))
                eventDescription.append(component.get('description'))
                startDate = component.get('dtstart')
                print (startDate.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))
                eventDateStart.append(startDate.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
                eventTimeStart.append(startDate.dt.strftime('%H:%M'))
                endDate = component.get('dtend')
                print (endDate.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))
                eventdateEnd.append(endDate.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
                eventTimeEnd.append(endDate.dt.strftime('%H:%M'))
                dateStamp = component.get('dtstamp')
                print (dateStamp.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))
                print ('')

    # Modify or change these values based on your CalDAV
    # Converting to JSON
    data = [{ 'Events Summary':eventSummary[0], 'Event Description':eventDescription[0],'Event Start date':eventDateStart[0], 'Event End date':eventdateEnd[0], 'At:':eventTimeStart[0], 'Until':eventTimeEnd[0]}]
    data_string = json.dumps(data)
    print ('JSON:', data_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to provide more details about how you are actually making use of the API but in case the query command is indeed not implemented, there is a list of other Python libraries at the [CalConnect website](https://web.archive.org/web/20160728055536/http://calconnect.org/caldav/implementations/librariestools.html) (archvied version, [original link](http://calconnect.org/caldav/implementations/librariestools.html) is dead now).

Comment: This page is dead now

Answer (score 0):

[pyOwnCloud](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=display&name=pyOwnCloud) could be the right thing for you. I haven't tried it, but it should provide a CMDline/API for reading the calendars.