# Access Fastmail CalDAV with Python

Tags: python, caldav

I'm trying to access my Fastmail calendar through Python. I'm using the `caldav` module as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634052/python-library-to-access-a-caldav-server). This is what my code looks like:

```
def main():
    auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username='mail@domain.com', password='myapplicationpassword')
    client = caldav.DAVClient('https://caldav.fastmail.com', auth=auth)
    try:
        client.principal()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

And `client.principal()` raises an exception:

```
404 Not Found

b'<html>\r\n<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor="white">\r\n<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

I also tried with `client = caldav.DAVClient('https://caldav.fastmail.com', username='mail@domain.com', password='myapplicationpassword')` and achieved the same result.

Finally, I took a look at the [caldav example using iCloud](https://github.com/python-caldav/caldav/blob/master/example/icloud_example.py), and tried to reproduce the same idea with fastmail. I ran into the very same issue (`principal_response` has a 404 status code).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The correct URL is `https://caldav.fastmail.com/dav`. This is not obvious from the servers and ports documentation.