# Recurring exceptions in ICal

Tags: icalendar

### Problem

Some reoccurring events, that don't really end at some point (like club meetings?), depend on other conditions (like holiday season). However, manually adding these exceptions would be necessary every year, as the dates might differ.

**Research**

- I have found out about `exdate` (see the image of ["iCalendar components and their properties"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) on Wikipedia [(2)](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/exdate.html))
- Also found some possible workaround: 'just writing a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408097/parsing-files-ics-icalendar-using-python) to do process such events'. This would still mean I need to process a `.ics` manually and import it into my calendar, which implies some limitations:

  - can not be determined for all time spans (e.g. holidays not fixed for more than three years)
  - these events would probably be separate and not reoccurring/'grouped', which makes further edits harder

### Question

> Is there a way to specify recurring exceptions in iCal ?

- To clarify, I have a recurring event *and* recurring exceptions.
- So for instance I have a *infinitely reoccurring weekly* event, that depends on the month; where it might only take place *if it's not* e.g. January, August, or December.

> Is there a way to use another event (/calendar) to filter events by boolean logic ?

If one could use a second event (or several) to plug into `exdate` this would solve the first problem and add some more possibilities.

---

**note**
if this question is too specific and the original problem could be solved by other means (other calendar-formats), feel free to comment/edit/answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[RFC2445 defines an `EXRULE`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445#section-4.8.5.2) (exception rule) property. You can use that in addition to the `RRULE` to define recurring exceptions.

However, RFC2445 was superseded by [RFC5545, which unfortunately deprecates the `EXRULE`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#appendix-A.3) property. So, client support is questionable.

As you already proposed, automatically adding `EXDATE` properties is a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks! Definitively good to know that it would be possible to use a rule instead of a list as an ‘EXDATE‘. Though, it is useless due to the second information and sadly does not solve the initial problem. Lets hope for an update that allows this usage again.

Answer (score 1):

`BYMONTH` would be another possibility, e.g. here's a rule for a club meeting that occurs the first Wednesday of every month except December (which is their Christmas party, so no business meeting)

```
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=1WE;BYMONTH=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It is getting close to a proper solution. Is there an overview over these filters? For example, is there 'BYWEEK' ? Googling leads to something else. This way one could define most holiday-exceptions (a bit tediously maybe).