# Remove subject from .ics file - python

Tags: python, icalendar

I need ur help with calendar in .ics format. I would like to remove subject appointment (text after 'SUMMARY:') from calendar with python and save it as .ics. How can I do this? Below I insert a piece of text from my .ics file.

```
SEQUENCE:0
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT5M
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:f468cba2-38bf-4fb1-ace1-1c6e6a9cde91
SUMMARY:
  This is a test text. This is a test text. This is a test text. This is a te
 test text.
LOCATION:calend1\;
ORGANIZER;CN=Kalendarz1:mailto:kalendarz1@nask.pl
DTSTART;TZID="Europe/Warsaw":20180529T123000
DTEND;TZID="Europe/Warsaw":20180529T130000
STATUS:CONFIRMED
CLASS:PUBLIC
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
TRANSP:OPAQUE
```

Comment: Use [something like this](https://pypi.org/project/ics/) probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is not a valid ICS file (note `END:VEVENT` before `START:VEVENT` and `SEQUENCE` outside any object). As such, you cannot use [an ICS parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408097/parsing-files-ics-icalendar-using-python). Depending on where you got this file, and whether its consumer expects ICS or this broken ICS-adjacent format, you may want to invest in fixing the file.

To just strike the subject can simply use a regular expression though:

```
import re

with open('test.ics', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as icsf:
    broken_ics = icsf.read()

out = re.sub(r'\nSUMMARY:(?:.*(?:\n )?)*', '', broken_ics)
print(out)
```

Comment: This regex is what I was looking for. Thank You very much and have a nice day! :)